# Dynamically change user claims/authentication state blazor server

Tags: authentication, authorization, blazor-server-side

I am working on an app that allows an admin type user to change the access permissions of a regular user.

I am using blazor server and mudblazor. I currently have it set up so an admin can click a user and see a list of available site permissions, which are stored as user claims.

I would like for the changes to be effective immediately, without disrupting the logged in user.

I have so far been able to nearly get it working. The problem is when setting the new authstate for the logged in user, it sets that authstate claimsPrincipal.Identity to null.

It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561815/dynamically-change-user-roles-authentication-state-blazor-server). But I didn't want to hijack the thread.

I am using a custom RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider class.

```
public class RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<TUser>
        : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider where TUser : class
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly IdentityOptions _options;

    public RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(loggerFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the authentication state asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authenticationState">The authentication state.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="TaskTResult"/> representing the result of the asynchronous operation.
    /// </returns>
    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a logger to log any errors
        var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync));

        // Create a new scope to ensure fresh data is fetched
        var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        try
        {
            //logger.LogInformation("{authenticationstate}", (authenticationState.User is null));
            // Get the user manager from the scope
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
            // Validate the security stamp of the user
            return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Dispose of the scope
            if (scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            {
                await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the security stamp of a user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userManager">The user manager.</param>
    /// <param name="principal">The claims principal.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the security stamp is valid, false otherwise.</returns>
    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<TUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        // Create a logger to log information
        var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(ValidateSecurityStampAsync));

        // Get the user from the user manager
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        logger.LogInformation("user name test: {test}", principal.Identity.Name);
        // If the user is null, return false
        if (user == null)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("user is null?");
            return false;
        }
        // If the user manager does not support user security stamp, return true
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Otherwise, get the security stamp from the principal and the user
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(_options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            logger.LogInformation("this thing {is}, principal stamp {stamp1}, authtype {type}, user stamp {stamp2}", _options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType, principalStamp, principal.Identity.AuthenticationType, userStamp);
            // Return true if the security stamps match
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }

    public async Task RequestReauthentication(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a logger to log information
        var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(RequestReauthentication));
        logger.LogInformation("get auth method called");

        // Create a new scope to ensure fresh data is fetched
        var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        try
        {
            // Get the user manager from the scope
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();

            var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal);
            if (user is not null && claimsPrincipal.Identity is not null)
            {
                var claims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
                var newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, claimsPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType));
                var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(newPrincipal));
                NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("exception: {message}", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Dispose of the scope
            if (scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            {
                await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RequestReauthentication is called on the user who had their claims changed. That user while logged in will see the changes on the page dynamically. But then when ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync is called, which calls ValidateSecurityStampAsync, the user is returned null. Then the state is changed to unauthorized.

is there anything I can do to get this working? or should I go a different route and have the user notified and logged out in like 10 minutes/unless the claim is critical, and it immediately logs the user out.

the code is messy because I fairly new to coding and just trying to work my way through it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Okay, so it only sort of works. I have a button behind a autorizedview with a specific policy. I can add a remove that permission a bunch and see the button appear and go away. But then shortly after something breaks and that behavior stop working. I'm still at a loss.

Dang it. Literally just after posting I continued trying stuff and found a solution! Well, if anyone else tries to do this, here is how. Simple of course.

I cloned the input identity with the Clone() method, which I just discovered. I had tried to just pass the identity through before, but that didn't work.

```
public async Task RequestReauthentication(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create a logger to log information
    var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(RequestReauthentication));
    logger.LogInformation("get auth method called");

    // Create a new scope to ensure fresh data is fetched
    var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    try
    {
        // Get the user manager from the scope
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();

        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal);
        if (user is not null && claimsPrincipal.Identity is not null)
        {

            // Clone current identity
            var clone = claimsPrincipal.Clone();
            var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

            var claims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            var newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(newIdentity, claims));
            //var newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, claimsPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType));
            var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(newPrincipal));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError("exception: {message}", ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Dispose of the scope
        if (scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
        {
            await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            scope.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```